# Case-insensitive NSString comparison

Tags: string, cocoa, nsstring, case-sensitive

Using this code I am able to compare string values.

```
[elementName isEqualToString: @"Response"]
```

But this compares case-sensitively. Is there a way to compare the string without case sensitivity?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There’s a `caseInsensitiveCompare:` method on `NSString`, why don’t you read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)? The method returns `NSComparisonResult`:

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

…ah, sorry, just now I realized you are asking for *case sensitive* equality. (Why don’t I read the question? :-) The default `isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:` equality should already be case sensitive, what gives?

Comment: +1 - So many handy methods, so little time spent reading the class reference docs. :-)

Comment: I believe there is always better way of saying "why don’t you read the documentation?", thanks for your answer btw.

Answer (score 14):

Here's the code you would need to compare a string without caring about whether it's lowercase or uppercase:

```
if ([elementName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Response"]==NSOrderedSame)
{
    //  Your "elementName" variable IS "Response", "response", "reSPonse", etc
    //  
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually isEqualToString: works with case sensitive ability.
as:

```
[elementName isEqualToString: @"Response"];
```

if you want to ask for case insensitive compare then here is the code:

You can change both comparable string to lowerCase or uppercase, and can compare as:

```
NSString *tempString = @"Response";
NSString *string1 = [elementName lowercaseString];
NSString *string2 =  [tempString lowercaseString];

//The same code changes both strings in lowerCase.
//Now You Can compare

if([string1 isEqualToString:string2])
{

//Type your code here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string1 = @"stringABC";
NSString *string2 = @"STRINGDEF";
NSComparisonResult result = [string1 caseInsensitiveCompare:string2];

if (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
  NSLog(@"string1 comes before string2");
} else if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
  NSLog(@"We're comparing the same string");
} else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
   NSLog(@"string2 comes before string1");
}
```