# help with NSdictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableArray where each item is an NSMutableDictionary.

```
 NSMutableAray *services = [NSMutableArray new];

 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [dict setObject: aNetService forKey: @"net_service"];
 [dict setObject: [aNetService name] forKey: @"net_service_name"];

 [self.services addObject:dict];
```

Then I want to retrieve an item according to the "net_service_name" key. So, I tried the following:

```
 -(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aBrowser didRemoveService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)more {

 NSLog(@"netservname%@",[aNetService name]);

 for (int i = 0; i < [services count]; i++)
 {

     NSDictionary *dict = [services objectAtIndex:i];
     NSLog(@"netservname%@",[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"]);

     if ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"]] == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[aNetService name]]){
         NSLog(@"Match");
     }
  }
}
```

In the console both NSLog(@"netservname") are the same, but I'm not getting the "Match" message. Can anyone see why? Thanks very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString compare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488877/nsstring-compare)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

`if ([[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"] isEqualToString:[aNetService name]])`.

`==` checks for identity, that is whether the two objects point to the same memory address.
`isEqualToString` checks for equality, in this case, that the two strings are the same characters in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"] isEqualToString:[aNetService name]]
```

Try that.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[aNetService name]]]
```

or

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"] isEqualToString:[aNetService name]]
```

`NSString isEqualToString:(NSString*)` http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

see: [Case-insensitive NSString comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488877/nsstring-compare)

Answer (score 2):

Because Objective-C uses pointers for everything you can't directly compare strings with the == operator.  What you're looking for is:

```
[string isEqualToString: otherString]
```

Answer (score 2):

Always use `isEqualToString:` for `NSString` comparison.

(And in general, always use `isEqual:` and its variants for `NSObject` comparisons)

*`NSObject*` and `NSString*` are pointers, so `==` do pointer comparison which is only true if the pointers are pointing to the exact same address in memory, which is quite never the case, while `isEqualToString:` check if the contents of the string are identical.*

---

Besides, you should prefer fast enumerations form for your for loop, and avoid doing stuff like `stringWithFormat:@"%@"` which are totally useless (you are creating a string using a format that will only contain... another string. Why don't you use the string itself directly?)

```
// NSFastEnumeration for to loop thru a NSArray
for (NSDictionary *dict in services)
{
  NSLog(@"netservname%@",[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"]);

  // Loose the [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",...] stuff!!
  if ([[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"] isEqualToString:[aNetService name]]) {
     NSLog(@"Match");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace if-statement with this one:

```
if ([[dict objectForKey:@"net_service_name"] compare:[aNetService name]] == NSOrderedSame)  {
    NSLog(@"Match");
}
```